# Google Maps v3 popup like Map Data

Tags: google-maps-api-3

[image]

Is there any way to use popup like google uses for Map Data? 
Did they provided any api for that?

I can't find anything about that...

Comment: Does the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) meet your needs?

Comment: No. It's designed for showing info of elements inside map "container". I should be over the map and don't move when draging tiles. Just like google uses for showing Map Data...

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look to [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/) ? It is probably what you're seeking for.
For information, you can go to [google-maps-utility-library-v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) and look if a library fits your needs.

Comment: No it is not what I asked for